# Cannot start Widget Update With Alarm Manager and PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I am trying for couple of days to solve this problem , hope someone can help me.

I am using Alarm Manager to make my widget update nay time i want (if to sue XML its only once in 30 min) so i made a pending intent and wrote it like in the examples that i found but , its updates only once when i compile the program.

Here is mu code:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        android.util.Log.w("FullTankWidget.UpdateService", "onUpdate()");

        Intent updateIntent = new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

       // alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, nextMinute.getTimeInMillis(),60000,pendingIntent);
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, firstTime + (60 * 1000), pendingIntent);

        android.util.Log.w("FullTankWidget.UpdateService", String.valueOf(firstTime));
        // To prevent any ANR timeouts, we perform the update in a service
        context.startService(new Intent(context,WidgetUpdateService.class));
```

the intent filter is writen in the manifest - defoult widget reciever

```
   <receiver android:name=".FullTankWidget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"     android:resource="@xml/fulltank_widget_config" />
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

But your alarmManager.setRepeating() line is commented out...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should also specify your class in the Intent.

```
updateIntent.setClass(context, YourProviderClassName.class);
```

Then it is subject of the PendingIntent. There is a PendingIntent filter working on the background that does not allow two similar Intents to be set as pending. So when it is called, it will be ignored if there is a similar intent to it.

If in your appwidget provider info you have a value set for *updatePeriodMillis* other than zero, then the system has already set a PendingIntent for updating. This is why **your new PendingIntent won't work**.

The solution is to disable updatePeriodMillis and use AlarmManager instead. The AlarmManager class has methods that help you set PendingIntents the way you want. But remember you will still have only one PendingIntent at a time.